# How to use PUBG API to invite players to my lobby or custom game?

Tags: api

Is there a way to use the [PubG API](https://documentation.pubg.com/en/introduction.html) to invite some players to create a party or to invite to a custom game.

With this API it's possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible according to the [FAQ](https://developer.pubg.com/faq?locale=en):

> Are custom Games available using the API? Can I use the API to create them?
>
> No, creating and controlling custom games is not possible with the API. However, data from custom games played within the last two weeks is available. Custom matches will show up alongside normal matches and they will have the attribute "isCustomMatch" set to "true".